# determine different origin for each function on the same plot in matlab

Tags: matlab

I got 2 functions, I want to plot each one of them from x=0 to x=10 but the first function I want it to start at x=0 and the second function I want to start at x=10 but from the value of x=0.
Is it possible? 
I tried so far this:

```
fplot(@(x) func1, [0 10])
hold on
fplot(@(x) func2, [10 20])
grid on
```

the problem is that I get the values of 10 till 20 for the second function but I want the values of 0 till 10 just to start at x=10, is it even possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use regular `plot`:

```
x = 0:0.1:10
plot(x,func1(x))
hold on
plot(x+10,func2(x))
```

Comment: So simple yet so useful, thanks.
Another question, is it possible to plot parametric? I mean that my x axis will be divided to 0 1/10L 2/10L 3/10L....L?

Comment: @RogerCloud If you mean change the ticklabels look at: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html